# php downloading file name

Tags: php, html, download

I`m looking for possibility to set the **same name** for download file.

I`m writing something like html-based editor, but file should be in special format, which builded on server-side after form submission.

As for now i see that if i already have file with that name - browser offers me "name(X).ext", where x is 1 to infinity.

php code is:

```
  header('Content-type: application/xhtml+xml');
  header("Content-Length: $data_length");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.xml");
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  echo $data;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Force new download to overwrite old one with same file name?

Comment: check the place where you set the $file_name. Try hard coding the file name like header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xml");

Comment: You cannot force an existing file to be over written. Your browser may offer you a different file name with the number as you mentioned. One possible solution to keep the file name how you want it, could be to add a timestamp to the filename. The browser will always have a unique name in that case.

Comment: @Godinall yes - that the target.

Comment: @Subdigger like AJReading said you can't override this because this is an OS behavior not you can bypass with client side code.

Comment: @AJReading yeah i know it but whant to make me assure. May be any other triks?

Comment: I don't believe there is. It's browser/OS behavior and so the only way to bypass it would to have a different file name each time you download.